# Finding the Unique values in column against row

Tags: sql

I have just started learning SQL , what i want is to write a query to get only the Column 2 value which doesn't have "D" present against them in Column 1.

For eg in the case below is "AC"

```
Column1 Column 2
A       AB
B       AB
C       AB
D       AB
A       AB
B       AB
C       AB
D       AB
A       AB
B       AB
A       AC
B       AC
C       AC
A       AC
B       AC
C       AC
A       AC
B       AC
C       AC
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good edit

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
select column1, coulmn2 from table_name where column1 != 'D'
```

`column1 != 'D'` removes the records from result which contains `D` in `column1`.

Similarly if you want to ignore more values from column1 you can use `not in`.

```
select column1, coulmn2 from table_name where column1 not in ('D','A')
```

**Update1**

To get count of records which doesn't have 'D' in `column1` you can use:

```
select count(*) from table_name where column1 != 'D'
```

Comment: Thanks it is showing me the record for only those which don't have "D" i want to find out how many entries are in "Column 2" which don't have D in Column 1.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan for your help but the query by Marvin worked in a way i want the data .

Answer (score 0):

See [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f85d/6) based on MySQL 5.6:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column2
FROM table_name
WHERE column2 NOT IN
(
    SELECT column2
    FROM table_name
    WHERE column1 = 'D'
);
```

There are basically two queries: the inner query fetches all `column2` values which have a corresponding `column1` with value `D`; the outer query fetches all `column2` values from your original table *excluding* the ones found by the inner query.

Data:

```
column1     column2
A           AB
B           AB
C           AB
D           AB
A           AC
B           AC
C           AC
A           AD
D           AD
D           AD
A           AE
```

Output:

```
column2
AC
AE
```